# Pegar as URLs da página de resultado de busca do Google

Tags: php, libcurl

Olá,

Gostaria de alguma API ou qualquer jeito de pegar as URLs que o Google retorna quando fizer uma busca.

Por exemplo, fiz uma busca no Google com cURL procurando por Walmarts, gostaria que o PHP me retornasse todas as URLs dos sites. Não achei nenhum método assim na web, poderiam me ajudar?

Grato desde já.

Comment: Você poderia colocar a chamada que está fazendo por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O google tem um serviço para isso:

- "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"
- "q=" + busca (exemplo "Star+Wars")
- "&cx=" + código da sua [CSE](https://cse.google.com/cse/all) (Custom Search Engine)
- "&key=" + Key da sua [API](https://console.developers.google.com/) [Crie uma API project, depois vá em 'APIs & auth' e ative em 'Custom Search API']

E seguida você terá algo parecido com isto:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Star+Wars&cx=018475493028468909364:ldifwlodnso&key=AOgsDiRlzY7GDCKC5Th7yKutv-7Hd4-IDehl_Sp
```

Você terá os resultados todos em JSON

Comment: Tem alguma CSE padrão?

Comment: Não, é gerado um para cada mecanismo de pesquisa que você criar! Para ter um uso mais amplo basta selecionar opções avançadas na hora de criar.

Comment: Essa resposta que você me deu acima, você por um acaso achou ela nesta pergunta? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405154/google-results-in-xml-json-using-the-custom-search-engine

Comment: Sim, já precisei e tinha o link salvo...

Comment: Mas só para constar, são fóruns diferentes...